# PowerShell - Invoke-Sqlcmd results to Export-Csv set batch row limit

Tags: windows, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm exporting about 1,000,000 rows via an `Invoke-Sqlcmd` script and it exports into a csv around 180MB.

What I would like to do is be able to export it instead into 10 100,000 row files.  How do I go about doing this as it doesn't seem to be a feature in `Export-Csv` or `Invoke-Sqlcmd` that I can find.

Current code:

```
$dataSubset = "mydata"
$localFile = ("{0}.csv" -f $dataSubset)
$localPath = "my\path"
$serverInstance = "myserver.domain.com"
$database = "mydatabase"

$Query = @"
my crazy ass query
"@
$Results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -QueryTimeout 0 -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $database -Query $Query
$Results | Export-csv $localPath/$localFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Instead of having a single `mydata.csv` I want to have `mydata_1.csv`, `mydata_2.csv`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet (whose built-in alias is `select`), it has `-Skip` and `-First` parameters:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    $localFile = ("{0}_{1}.csv" -f $dataSubset, $i)
    $Results | Select -Skip ($i * 100000) -First 100000 | Export-Csv $localPath/$localFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Good pointers, though you probably don't want to send the entire 1-million objects array through the pipeline for each and every batch; ideally, you'd avoid collecting all 1 million objects in memory to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as of PowerShell 7.0, there is no batching (chunking) mechanism in PowerShell.

- [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8270) suggests adding a `-ReadCount` parameter to `Select-Object` to enable batching.

For now, you'll have to implement your own:

```
# ... 

$batchSize = 10000
$fileNdx = 0

# The list to hold a batch.
$batch = [Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new($batchSize)

# The script block for exporting a single batch to a CSV.
# Exports to .../mydata_1.csv, .../mydata_2.csv, ... 
$sb = { 
        ++$fileNdx; 
        $batch | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$localPath/mydata_$fileNdx.csv" 
      }

Invoke-Sqlcmd -QueryTimeout 0 -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $database -Query $Query |
  ForEach-Object -Process {
    $batch.Add($_) # add object to current batch
    if ($batch.Count -eq $batchSize) { # batch is complete
      . $sb # export
      $batch.Clear() # start new batch
    }
  } -End { 
    if ($batch.Count) { # final, incomplete batch
      . $sb # export
    }
  }
```

Note that you should generally avoid `$Results = Invoke-Sqlcmd ...` with large queries, because it invariably collects the entire result set in memory *as a whole* - instead, use the *pipeline*, with its *object-by-object* processing, as shown above.
That said, if you have enough memory, capturing all input at once can situationally improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that powershell is the way to do this. Cant you export directy from the SQL Server via cmd integration?

Anyway, concerning your question, another Alterantive is:

```
$length = $Results.length


$items = 10;
$stepwitch = [Math]::Ceiling($length / $items)

for($i=1;$i -le $items; $i++) {
$firstItem = ($i - 1) * $stepwitch 
$lastItem = ($i * $stepwitch) - 1
if ($lastItem -gt $length) {$lastItem = $length}
echo ("FI: " + $firstItem + " LI:"  + $lastItem)
$localFile = ("{($i)}.csv" -f $dataSubset)
$Results[$firstItem..$lastItem] | Export-csv $localPath/$localFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

(not tested, but at the end similiar to Mark Arends solution)

Another alterantive would maybe to use the .net method system.array.copy https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netcore-3.1